# Is this a limit, or am I using the wrong word?

Tags: limits

I am looking at an equation that says:

$$z_\frac{1}{1000}(a, \lambda) = \frac{\ln(1000)a\lambda}{2\pi\sqrt{(\chi'_{mn}\lambda)^2 - a^2}}$$

What I want to say is something like, "as a becomes very small, the function becomes approaches being tangential $\frac{\ln(1000)a}{2\pi\chi'}$, where 'very small' means a small fraction of lambda". I'm pretty sure that's true, but I don't know if that's the same as saying $$\lim_{a \to 0} z_{\frac{1}{1000}}(a, \lambda)= \frac{\ln(1000)a}{2\pi\chi'}$$

It's been a *long* time since I took limits, and I'm not sure it's legal to put the variable in the limit on the left-hand side, too. Does this make any sense?

(There are a bunch of physics conditions involved in the specific problem enforcing that 0 < a < $\chi'_{mn}\lambda$)

Comment: You can't have the variable that tends to $0$ (or to any other number) appear on the right hand side of the calculation. It's supposed to have already disappeared from the calculation. Maybe you want to say something like that the expression you get when you divide the left hand side by the right hand side tends to $1$ as $a$ tends to $0$.

Comment: You are correct, this is not a limit. This is because the limit as $a\to 0$ can never have $a$ in it - it doesn’t depend on $a.$ $$\lim_{a\to 0} g(a)=\lim_{b\to 0} g(b),$$ so if the limit is $2a,$ does $2a=2b?$ No. You can write this instead by writing, “near $a=0,$ $$z(a,\lambda)\sim \frac{\ln(1000)a}{2\pi\chi’}.”$$ Or, equivalently, you can say $$\lim_{a\to0}\frac{z(a,\lambda)}{a}=\frac{\ln(1000)}{2\pi\chi’}$$

Comment: Yes, this is called an asymptotic equivalence https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis

Comment: What is a “behavior” in your question? @Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, this is not a limit.

This is because the limit as $a\to 0$ can never have $a$ in it - the limit as $a\to0$ can never depend on $a.$

One way to think of $\lim_{a\to0} f(a)$ is as the answer to the question, “What value should we give $f(0)$ to make $f$ continuous at $0?$” What would $a$ even mean in formula for the limit? $a$ isn’t even a variable in that question.

If $$\lim_{a\to 0} g(a)=\lim_{b\to 0} g(b),$$ so if the limit is $2a,$ does $2a=2b?$ No.

You can write this instead by writing,

> Near $a=0,$ $$z(a,\lambda)\sim \frac{\ln(1000)a}{2\pi\chi’}.$$

Or, equivalently, you can say:
$$\lim_{a\to0}\frac{z(a,\lambda)}{a}=\frac{\ln(1000)}{2\pi\chi’}$$

In general, we say $f(a)\sim g(a)$ near $a=a_0$ if $$\lim_{a\to a_0}\frac{f(a)}{g(a)}=1.$$

Often, when the context makes it clear, we skip the phrase “near $a=a_0.$”

I usually read $\sim$ as “is asymptotic to.” Wikipedia says the name is “on the order of” and the description is “$f$ is asymptotically equal to $g.$”

See the “Generalizations and related usages” and “ Family of Bachmann–Landau notations” sections [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation?wprov=sfti1)